# SQL Server send email when query result is not empty

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, triggers, job-scheduling

I need to send an email from SQL Server when a query result set holds records. The query can be based on a lot of logic with joins between several tables.

Please send me in the right direction (views, triggers on views, SQL Server agent job..?).

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a website for asking for tutorials, it's for asking for help to resolve coding problems you've already tried (and failed) to resolve. if you can show your attempts, and explain why they aren't working,we'll be happy to help you work out where you went wrong and why. Otherwise, if you're looking for tutorials, [Google](http://google.com), [Bing](http://bing.com), [DuckDuckGo](http://duckduckgo.com), etc, would be a good place to start; your title will likely give you useful hits. [Title](https://www.google.com/search?&q=SQL+server+send+email+when+query+result+is+not+empty)

Comment: A query does not "hold" rows. You (or something) must run a query in order to know if the resulting set of rows is empty or not. You need to take a step backwards and think about your goal - your business goal. I suggest you break this into pieces. You can easily find suggestions on sending an email from sql server. Get that working. Then figure out what event or situation is key to sending this email.

Answer (score 3):

using sp_send_DBmail as documented here(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  for all parameter options

```
declare @bodytext varchar(max)= '<b>Hey look I wrote something</b>'

if(Exists(select 1 from ....))
begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@recipients='xyz@gmail.com',
@subject='ATTN! There are records',
@body=@bodytext,
@body_format='HTML',
@from_address='DBA <kl@domain.com>',
@reply_to='xyz@gmail.com'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at Vsql-email app (you can search on google, I think I'm not allowed to post the direct link here), it has this option to not send the email if the query has 0 rows, and you can send the email as HTML formatted body and/or as excel attachment and no need to enable and configure Database Mail in SQL Server and write code for HTML formatting.

Comment: Question author would appreciate any code or configuration or any other examples, which can be used as a starting point.